# Save mysql array php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save an array of values into a MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
$values = array('jaime','11124583363', '5554625', '312458795','1999-12-02','soldierjesus', 'calle 12', 'carismatica', 'necesito oracion', '1', '1');

$data->create_persons('new_person', $values);

public function create_persons($table, $values)
{
    $query = ("INSERT INTO $table ('name', 'number_document','phone', 'cell_phone', 'birth_date', 'email',
                        'address', 'other_church', 'pray_request', 'districts_id', 'professions_id') 
                          VALUES('".implode("','", $values).")'") or die(mysqli_error());

    mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query);
}
```

The numbers are can't --> ''
How quit this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the numbers are can't"?

Answer (score 4):

change

```
VALUES('".implode("','", $values).")'")
```

into

```
VALUES('".implode("','", $values)."')")
```

in other words change the `")'"` into `"')"`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't give it much time, but I think the insert query is wrong here:

```
`$query = ("INSERT INTO $table ('name', 'number_document','phone', 'cell_phone', 'birth_date', 'email', 'address', 'other_church', 'pray_request', 'districts_id', 'professions_id') VALUES('".implode("','", $values)."')") or die(mysqli_error());`
```

The ' (single quote) to close the VALUES() was in the wrong place.

Regards,
Charlie